# Legal and tax implications of former H1B holder trading in IRA account from India?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, legal, h-1b-visa

I am a former H1B holder. I am now in India. While on H1B in the U.S., I established an IRA account.

My questions:

1. Can I use the IRA account to trade options and stocks legally?
2. If so, how can I pay taxes?
3. I do not like my current IRA planner due to their fees. Can I open a new IRA account in the U.S. while I am in India and transfer funds from my old IRA to the new IRA?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use the IRA account to trade options and stocks legally?

Yes. There are very specific things excluded from the IRA trading:

1. Insurance
2. Art and collectibles (except for explicitly approved bulion coins)
3. Real Estate (and especially leveraged real estate) require good amount of planning to be allowed.
4. Self-trading (i.e.: you cannot trade with yourself or with related entities)

IRS also prohibits contracts with unlimited loss potential, but covered calls are allowed (although not any custodian will allow them, there's no law against it).

> If so, how can I pay taxes?

You can mail a personal check to the IRS, or use your credit card when filing the extension and paying estimates online. However, IRA is a tax-deferred account, so unless you blow it up, you will only be paying taxes (at ordinary rates) on distributions, when you take them.

That said, the tax-deferral is a US law, India may not see the IRAs the same way and may tax your IRA earnings as current income. Talk to an Indian tax adviser about it.

> I do not like my current IRA planner due to their fees. Can I open a
>   new IRA account in the U.S. while I am in India and transfer funds
>   from my old IRA to the new IRA?

Is it IRA or 401k? These are different things.

Technically you can. Practically, however, it may be difficult for a non-resident to open an IRA account on-line. You'll need to check around which custodian will allow you opening an account. You'll need to certify your residency status, and most, if not all, on-line forms require this to be a W9 certification - you need W8-BEN/ECI.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can trade options and stocks in an IRA. Although retirement plans are presumed to be "hands off" investments that you don't manage much, but this is not well defined and your broker is not likely to penalize you for "overtrading". You won't be able to use margin though (no shorting), because there is no way for you to add money to an account if your trades go sour.

2) IRA accounts are not subject to capital gains tax. When distributions start (when you reach retirement age) you have to pay tax on the current value of the account, at the income tax rate. Roth IRA's have no tax on distribution but the contributions were already taxed.

3) Not sure about that, although you could try to use the information (name, address, KYC/AML stuff) that you gave to your previous planner and see if it still works to set up a new IRA, brokers do this via forms online, so as long as you can fund the account the only risk is that some AML procedure prompts the company to close your account.